# When using the android:process attribute to start a service is just the service class spawned as a process

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am wanting to spawn a service that extends IntentService.  What I am curious is which class is the bases of the process (using the android:process=":remote" attribute in the service manifest entry).

ie. say my app is mypackage.MyApp, and my service is myPackage.MyService, which class is run ?  is it the APP class, and the service runs as part of the app's main thread, or is MyService run as its own app ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it the APP class, and the service runs as part of the app's main thread

Yes.

Also, do not use `android:process=":remote"`, unless you are absolutely certain it is needed, as it wastes RAM+CPU and adds no value in most cases. I would guess that 1 app in 10,000 needs `android:process=":remote"` -- statistically speaking, your app does not need it.